# ASP.NET mvc angularjs post does not redirect

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

Why when i am making post request to `Login` `RedirectToAction` does not work and url do not change to `/Home/Second`.

AngularJS:

```
$scope.answer = function(answer) {
  $mdDialog.hide(answer);
  $http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'Home/Login',
      data: JSON.stringify({ email: $scope.user.email, password: $scope.user.password })
  });
};
```

HomeController:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Home/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Second()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(string email,string password)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Second");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of redirect it from controller you can redirect it from Angular js code like below;

Your Js code will be

```
 $scope.answer = function(answer) {
          $mdDialog.hide(answer);
          var response = $http({
              method: 'POST',
              url: 'Home/Login',
              data: JSON.stringify({ email: $scope.user.email, password: $scope.user.password })
          });

       if(response == "Success")
       {
          $window.location.href = "/Home/Second";
       }

    });
```

And in your controller you have to write your method like this:

```
 public string Login(string email,string password)
 {
        return "Success";
 }
```